# Unselect all Select dropdown options except for current selection

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 separate select dropdowns but the user should only be able to select one option among the 4. So far I've tried deselecting previously selected options but I haven't been able to target the current selection.

```
<select name="hood_select" class="form-control hood-selection">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Manhattan</option>
    <option value="upper manhattan">Upper Manhattan (North of W. 110th St.)</option>
    <option value="upper east side">Upper East Side (E. 60th St. to E. 128th St.)</option>
    <option value="upper west side">Upper West Side (W. 59th St. to W. 110th St.)</option>
</select>

<select name="hood_select" class="form-control hood-selection">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Brooklyn</option>
    <option value="greenpoint">Greenpoint</option>
    <option value="all other areas">All other areas</option>
</select>

<select name="hood_select" class="form-control hood-selection">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Queens</option>
    <option value="astoria">Astoria</option>
    <option value="woodside">Woodside</option>
    <option value="all other areas">All other areas</option>
</select>

<select name="hood_select" class="form-control hood-selection">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Other Areas</option>
    <option value="bronx">Bronx</option>
    <option value="new jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

I've included the incomplete js below as well. Thanks in advance!

```
 $('select.hood-selection').change(function () {
    $('select.hood-selection').each(function() {
        $('select.hood-selection option').removeAttr("selected");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all Replace :

```
 $('select.hood-selection option').removeAttr("selected");
```

with:

```
$(this).find('option').removeAttr("selected");
```

inside the loop to have current element reference on which we are iterating.

and you can use `not()` to exclude the current dropdown which is changed:

```
$('select.hood-selection').change(function () {
var currentSelected = this; // save reference of current dropdown
    $('select.hood-selection').each(function() {
            $(this).not(currentSelected).find('option').removeAttr("selected");
        });
 });
```

or:

```
$('select.hood-selection').change(function () {
        $('select.hood-selection').not(this).each(function() {
                $(this).find('option').removeAttr("selected");
            });
     });
```

### UPDATE:

As OP mentioned he want to select the first `option` of other dropdown list, you can use `eq()` , you have to pass index as passing **0** index will select the first `option` of `select`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select.hood-selection').change(function () {

        $('select.hood-selection').not(this).each(function () {
            $(this).find('option:eq(0)').prop("selected", true);
        });
    });
});
```

### DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/aop5cpoc/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This selects 1 from each then seems to disable afterwards http://jsfiddle.net/aop5cpoc/

Comment: I see that my initial selections might cause a problem with this solution. Maybe I can add a class to each initially selected option in order to return each to that state

Comment: you want to reset to default or select previous selected option?

Comment: I'm looking to have each return to their initial selection. Right now they still stay selected in one way or another. So maybe for all others we select their :first-child?

Comment: You're a god among men. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I am just a sinner person of the kind God @Jamie. Glad it helped..:)